# Static_Root in settings.py redirecting to my static folder in app instead of base root

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am having a hard time deploying a project to heroku, because it says it cannot find the static files. My static files are in an app called 'social' in a folder called 'static', they aren't in the base directory where manage.py is.
--p_12 (folder)- settings.py
--social (folder) -static (folder) - css, images, javascript
--manage.py

The heroku docs says to put this in your settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')   
STATIC_URL = '/static/'     
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

So my question, how do I get this to point to my static folder in my social app. I've honestly tried for like an hour on this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Side note: You always want to have directory stricture for static and template files as. social->static -> social -> files. That way when you run collectstatic your static files will be more organized.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Here's the thing You do not want to point your static root to your social. That is what django best practise says.

According to your current settings (considering you have not changed BASE_DIR). You telling django to look for static files in a folder called **staticfiles**, which is at root level.

```
project_root
|__manage.py
|__staticfiles
|__app_name
|__requirements.txt
```

when you run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

django looks for all the folders named static and copies its contents and puts them at static_root.

in your case, contents are getting dumped into staticfiles.

after runing collectstaic command ideally this is what you want in your staticfiles folder.

```
staticfiles
|___app_1
|    |___css
     |___js
     |___images  
|
|___app_2
     |___css
     |___js
     |___images
```

Once this is in place django should be able to find static files in production.

but for this to happen. Make sure in your app your store static files like this.

```
app_name
|____static
        |___app_name
        |        |____css
                 |____js
                 |____images
```

Arrange files in this format and run collectstaic. make sure staticfiles has the contents mentioned as above. you should be good.

Comment: So will it automatically create a 'staticfiles' folder in the root for me after it gathers my app's 'static' folders? Or I need to create an empty 'staticfiles' folder? Or I should myself remove all the 'static' folders in my apps and put them all in the one 'staticfiles' folder.

Comment: It will create a staticfiles folder by itself. But doing it manually and copying and pasting  static folders manually works as well.

Comment: Okay good thanks, I had no idea that's what was happening. If you don't mind one more question. The STATICFILES_DIRS tells the computer to look for the 'static' folders in my apps? (to like you said then be put in the static_root). If I changed STATICFILES_DIRS to = 'monkey' it would look for folders in my apps called 'monkey'?

Comment: no matter what you put in STATICFILES_DIRS, it will always look in static folders. for current setup STATICFILES_DIRS is not adding any value. but sure if you put monkey in there it would go and look in monkey folder.